# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: sendmail, sendgrid, java-5

Hi I want to use sendGrid Mail Sending feature in Java 1.5
as follows

EmailUtil.sendEmail("reciever", "sender", "subject", "body", "contentType", "apiKey");

Since that exception tells that version does not permit...
Is there any alternate to use this feature in Java 1.5

Here is the full Stack of Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to send mail using SendGrid through the common SMTP protocol.

Information about that option can be found under the following URL:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html

To communicate using the SMTP protocol you may use the standard JavaMail API or a wrapper eg. Apache Commons Email. The latest version of commons email is still compatible with Java 1.5.